# How to divide this xpath into two parts using selenium JAVA?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Actual xpath: `(//div[@style='display: table-row;']//following-sibling::div)[38]`

I am trying to divide this above xpath into 2 parts like this: `//div[@style='display: table-row;']` & `./following-sibling::div[38]`.

This below code not working:

```
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@style='display: table-row;']"));
            WebElement f = e.findElement(By.xpath("./following-sibling::div[38]"));
 System.out.println(f.getText());
```

But it's showing **no element exception** for `WebElement f`.

Answer (score 0):

The original xpath contains a double slash after the `div`, while the xpath used in selenium only one. So you have to use

```
WebElement f = e.findElement(By.xpath(".//following-sibling::div[38]"));
```

where notice `.//` instead of `./`.

A double slash `//` means any descendant node of the current node, while a single slash `/` means a node which is a direct child of the current.

Here you can see an easy example to understand the difference:

[image]

and the corresponding code in selenium (notice 1 element vs 3 elements)

[image]

Comment: not working with `.//`. In Actual xpath I enclosed whole xpath in brackets.

Comment: @MaddenCrush can you share url of the page?

Comment: @MaddenCrush its data18(.)com